# Inserting submit form in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

i have the following button in my code, and upon the pressing of the button, i should be getting a value from a textfield (input) which value is "username", how can i add the submit method inside the button in order to get the $_POST["username"] value?

```
    <form method="post">
    ...

    <td>
    <?php  $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    echo" <a href=\"../pfe/user.php?update&id=$id&username2=$username\"         
    class=\"button yellow\">Update</a><br>"; ?></td>
    ...
    </form>
```

Comment: .... what? you mean like `<input type="submit" name="submit" />` ?

Comment: exactly @Epodax , can i do that ? or how should it be ?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you find a tutorial on how to use forms / html.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create  tag for getting username in $_POST. You can just add one input field like below example and once you submit the form you will get the desired dat in $_POST -

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
```

For submitting form you can add one submit button like this -

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Below will be your complete code -

```
<form method="post" action="somefile.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now when you will press submit button your form will be posted to 'somefile.php' and form values will be available in $_POST.

Comment: i know , but how am supposed to get the value unless i have used some kind of "submit"

Answer (score 0):

```
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $link = "../pfe/user.php?update&id=".$id."&username2=".$username;
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $link;?>">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: looks good but i still think we r still missing something, i tried your code and the value of username2 is still empty. "http://localhost/pfe/user.php?update&id=0&username2= "

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This HTML 5 submit form    



<html>
    <body>
     <form action="action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
      First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
     </body>
    </html>`enter code here`
```